# VM running under Hyper-V thinks it connects to a new network after every host reboot

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I have turned a physical machine running Windows 10 21H1 into a virtual machine that I run under Hyper-V on a new machine running Windows 10 21H2.

Networking-wise, the VM is configured with two network adapters connected to one virtual switch each: one that is linked to the wifi adapter on the host machine, and the second one is just an internal network.

Whenever I reboot the host machine, upon the next restart of the VM, it always thinks it is connected to a new network and pops up the "*do you want your pc to be discoverable*" prompt on the sidebar.

[image: do you want your pc to be discoverable prompt]

How can I configure it so that it recognize the network as the same one it has already been connected to? Is this something controlled by a setting in the virtual switch configuration, in the network adapter settings in hyper-v, or something in the VM itself?

Comment: Has [`cloud-init`](https://blogs.vmware.com/management/2019/01/windows-cloud-init-solution.html) and/or [`Azure agent`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows) been installed on the VM?

Comment: Nope, no cloud-init or Azure tools have been installed. This is not running on Azure.

Comment: Is the new network discovered on your virtual internal network or on your bridged wireless network?

Comment: @ekkim It's on the bridged wireless network

Comment: whenever you use wireless its get always a new id so that windows cant re-identify the same network since its basically always a new one